# Intuitively arguing that the determinant of Lorentz boost matrices is unity

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

The Lorentz transformations can be derived from (a) Principle of Relativity and (2) group axioms. I was looking at the derivation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#From_group_postulates), and I have problem understanding one specific step. In the derivation one somehow argues that the determinant of the matrix should be $1$. That is done in the following steps, I quote directly,

> Combining these two gives $\alpha=\gamma$ and the transformation matrix has simplified,
> $$
> \left[\begin{array}{l}
> t^{\prime} \\
> x^{\prime}
> \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
> \gamma & \delta \\
> -v \gamma & \gamma
> \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
> t \\
> x
> \end{array}\right]
> $$
> Now consider the group postulate inverse element. There are two ways we can go from the $K$ coordinate system to the $K$ coordinate system. The first is to apply the inverse of the transform matrix to the $K$ coordinates:
> $$
> \left[\begin{array}{l}
> t \\
> x
> \end{array}\right]=\frac{1}{\gamma^{2}+v \delta \gamma}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
> \gamma & -\delta \\
> v \gamma & \gamma
> \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
> t^{\prime} \\
> x^{\prime}
> \end{array}\right]
> $$
> The second is, considering that the $K$ coordinate system is moving at a velocity $v$ relative to the $K$ coordinate system, the $K$ coordinate system must be moving at a velocity $-v$ relative to the $K$ coordinate system. Replacing $v$ with $-v$ in the transformation matrix gives:
> $$
> \left[\begin{array}{l}
> t \\
> x
> \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
> \gamma(-v) & \delta(-v) \\
> v \gamma(-v) & \gamma(-v)
> \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
> t^{\prime} \\
> x^{\prime}
> \end{array}\right]
> $$
> Now the function $\gamma$ can not depend upon the direction of $v$ because it is apparently the factor which defines the relativistic contraction and time dilation. These two (in an isotropic world of ours) cannot depend upon the direction of $v$. Thus, $\gamma(-v)=\gamma(v)$ and comparing the two matrices, we get
> $$
> \gamma^{2}+v \delta \gamma=1
> $$

But comparing last two matrices I get,

$$\delta(-v)=\frac{-\delta}{\gamma^2+v\delta\gamma}$$
Therefore the determinant of the transformation matrix is $1$ only if $-\delta=\delta(-v)$. But how to argue that? I don't see the argument being presented here. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two matrices are equal, then they are equal component-wise.  If you compare the top left entries of the two matrices, then you find that
$$\gamma(-v) = \frac{\gamma(v)}{\gamma^2 + v\delta \gamma}$$

Since you've argued that $\gamma(-v)=\gamma(v)$, the result follows directly.  If you then compare the top *right* entries of the two matrices, you find that indeed $\delta(-v)=-\delta(v)$ as well.

Comment: OK! I have been really stupid! It is obvious.